# Inlining XML elements

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have the following models:

```cs
public PersonInfo
{
    [XmlElement("initials")]
    public string Initials { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("prefix")]
    public string Prefix { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("familyName")]
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public ContactPerson
{
    [XmlElement("department")]
    public string Department { get; set; }

    public PersonInfo PersonInfo { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public Driver
{
    [XmlElement("vehicleID")]
    public string VehicleId { get; set; }

    public PersonInfo PersonInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to inline the properties of `PersonInfo` when serializing with `XmlSerializer` so that I get

```xml
<contactPerson>
  <department>SillyWalks</department>
  <initials>J</initials>
  <familyName>Time</familyName>
</contactPerson>
```

instead of

```xml
<contactPerson>
  <department>SillyWalks</department>
  <PersonInfo>
    <initials>J</initials>
    <familyName>Time</familyName>
  </PersonInfo>
</contactPerson>
```

Inheritance is not an option because I have multiple models like these that needs to be inlined.

Comment: Only way I know using Serializer is to use an IXmlSerializer interface : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable?view=net-7.0  Using Xml Linq (or any other net library) it can also be done.